# Fastest way to retrieve filtered remote event logs

Tags: c#, windows, logging, .net-core

I need to retrieve a few event logs (with specific IDs) from the `Security` event log from a handful of servers.

I've parallelized the server loop and it works fine and speeds up, but a couple of them have -huge- retention strategies (exported EVTX files for full registries are over 10gb).

I get the logs using a loop like this:

```cs
var eventIds = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
var eventIdQueryStr = string.Join(" or ", eventIds.Select(x => $"EventID={x}"));
var queryXPath = $"*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime >= '{dateFrom:s}' and @SystemTime < '{dateTo:s}']]] and *[System[{eventIdQueryStr}]]";

using var session = new EventLogSession(
    serverName,
    domain,
    user,
    password,
    SessionAuthentication.Default);

var eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, queryXPath) {Session = session};
using (var logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery))
{
    for (var eventDetail = logReader.ReadEvent();
        eventDetail != null;
        eventDetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
    {
        // event list is a `ConcurrentBag<EventRecord>`
        _eventList.Add(eventDetail);
        /* other irrelevant stuff for showing progress, not relevant to the speed of the process */
    }
}
/* Parsing of the eventList here... irrelevant to the question */
```

This works, but it's **extremely** slow. I get around 1 million records (filtered with the xpath query) per hour for each server (not counting the parsing, that's why it's not relevant here) over a VPN.

I understand the event log on Windows is not an indexed database so the query doesn't really speed up things (just filters them), but this is the fastest I could get (with several different techniques, including dumping the whole registry on the remote server, copying the file and/or parsing it directly via the network).

Is there anything I'm missing which could speed it up?

I've tested this on both .NET Core 3.0 and .NET Framework 4.8 with no difference on results whatsoever. Using the `wevtutil` command line with the same xpath query (using `/q:"<query>"`) give similar performance but I can't get over my head that this is the fastest that can be done.

The servers with big retention in particular are dual xeon servers with LOTS of free CPU and RAM, so I'm quite positive this is not a hardware performance problem.

I'd be grateful for any tips

PS: when I wrote the "progress-showing" parts are irrelevant is because I've tried removing them (just in case outputting progress was the culprit) with no relevant differences to the process speed